# Comments appear in wrong posts

Tags: comments

Nasty problem here!

Comments are not connected to the right posts but to other ones!

Passing from disquss to jetpack comments doesnt't fix this.

What could be the solution?

The site is http://www.zonasismica.sism.org/

Thanks!

UPGRADE!
Seems like disqus is the problem... My team use to publish posts in chunks. It seems that diqus cannot distinguish between posts when their pub time are too close. All the posts in one chunk show the same comments. Check zonasismica.sism.org/~
~- lincaricato-locale-tra-deriva-dittatoriale-e-leader-democratico-problematiche-dilemmi-e-psicodrammi-di-un-il
 - do-you-know-climate-change
 - calcutta-village-project-e-noi-dove-siamo
 - i-cinque-segreti-dellarea-scopescore

If I turn off diqus, the posts again appear in one post only, but of course not were wanted to see them!

Comment: Sounds like a overwrite to the main loop, finding the problem without looking the actual code its difficult, can you show us the code involved in that request? (single.php, comments.php, sidebar.php, etc...)

Comment: Is this a Jetpack/Disqus plugin problem or do you have the same issue with the default theme and all plugins disabled?

Comment: do you recognize any pattern with the wrong comments? have you checked the 'related posts' section? have you contacted the theme's developer, as you are using a commercial theme?

Comment: I checked, the only pattern I'm seeing is that the articles with the mixed comments are subsequent and with a publication time almost identical. But other